# Why this orphaned process is called by a child process of init instead of init?

Tags: process, c

I know that all orphaned process are taken over by the init process(mother process) but I wrote a c program to understand how processes really work and I notice that a orphaned process is taken over by a child process of init. I want to know why is this happening?

**C Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
        {
                printf("An error occured\n");
                exit(98);
        }

        if (pid == 0)
        {
                sleep(10);
                pid_t id = getppid();
                pid_t id1 = getpid();
                printf("PPID: %u PID: %u\n", id, id1);
        }

        else
        {

                pid_t id = getppid();
                pid_t id1 = getpid();
                printf("PPID: %u PID: %u\n", id, id1);
        }

        return (0);
}
```

**Processes**

```
root           1       0  0 Jul27 ?        00:00:06 /sbin/init splash
maxwell     2180       1  0 Jul27 ?        00:00:03 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
maxwell     7039    2180  0 00:49 pts/1    00:00:00 ./a.out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [A]ll orphaned process are taken over by the init process.

This is no longer the case on Linux. In version 3.4, Linux gained the "subreaper" functionality. See [this answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250156/70524) for a full explanation, but the gist is that when a process becomes an orphan, then the kernel signals the closest ancestor process that is marked as a subreaper (falling back to init if there are none). When systemd starts a user session by running a session init process (what you see as `/lib/systemd/systemd --user`), it marks itself as a subreaper, so orphan processes in that session will (likely) be re-parented to the session init, not the system init process.

Comment: Thanks alot but why on virtual machine the init process is used?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea whether it's a virtual machine or not makes no difference

Comment: I means when using VM the mother process is used. Why that is happening?

Comment: And I'm saying that whether you use a VM or not makes no difference. It depends on what you installed in the VM, how you logged into it and how you ran the test. You'd see the same behaviour on a physical system if you installed the same things, logged in the same way and ran the test the same way.